# Taking back your capital from your S-corporation

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, self-employment, s-corporation

If I put 100k of my own money into my business, and now my business made 150k, can I take out my 100k without it being taxable? If so, how would that be inputted onto the k-1?

Comment: K-1 is for partnerships.  Wouldn't taking your whole equity stake out of the partnership... dissolve the partnership?

Comment: How did you put the $100k in? As a loan, or as equity, or something else?

Comment: i put it as equity, but can you please explain the difference

Comment: @RonJohn: there are K-1's for 1065 (partnership), 1120S (S-corp), and 1041 (estate or trust), all of which are broadly similar but different in detail.